# What would be an example where std::bit_cast produces a value representation of multiple values?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The following is a quote from the standard (draft n4861) under [bit.cast] (emphasizes are mine)

> *Returns:* An object of type `To`. Implicitly creates objects nested within the result (6.7.2). Each bit of the value representation of the result is equal to the corresponding bit in the object representation of `from`. Padding bits of the result are unspecified. For the result and each object created within it, if there is no value of the object’s type corresponding to the value representation produced, the behavior is undefined. **If there are multiple such values, which value is produced is unspecified**.

So my question is, what would be an example of a scenario where `std::bit_cast` produces a value representation that is corresponded to multiple different values?

Comment: I'm not a specialist, but something like `NaN` and `Infinity` comes to mind...

Comment: @sklott Positive zero, negative zero, NaN... they are different values that might compare equal w/ the incorrect equality operator but result in different values in many operations and can be distinguished.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sum types come to mind. A union can have members of the same type:

```cpp
union u {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Now, if we bit-cast something into a `u`, what sort of `u` do we get? Is it one where `a` is active or `b`? Those are formally different values of a `u`, but they would seem to have the same value representation.

Answer (score 5):

In the original proposal, that paragraph was written as: http://wg21.link/P0476r1

> Returns: an object of type `To` whose *object representation* is equal to the object representation of `From`. If multiple *object representations* could represent the *value representation* of `From`, then it is unspecified which `To` value is returned. If no *value representation* corresponds to `To`'s *object representation* then the returned value is unspecified.

So it seems like the intention was that padding bits are allowed to be changed. That is, there are multiple possible object representations for the same value representation of `From` with different padding, so there are multiple possible value representations in `To` with different values. For example, when `bit_cast`ing like this:

```cpp
struct foo {
    std::uint8_t a;
    // 1 byte padding to align
    std::uint16_t b;
};

bit_cast<std::uint32_t>(foo_value);
```

The padding byte is allowed to be different (so multiple `bit_cast`s are allowed to return different values, but round-trip bit casting will conserve value in this case)

---

But there seems to be situations that break round-tripping. Consider this case (https://godbolt.org/z/KGTGes):

```cpp
int a[1];
int b[1];
assert(std::begin(a) == std::end(b));  // 1

std::uintptr_t a_bits = std::bit_cast<std::uintptr_t>(std::begin(a));
std::uintptr_t b_bits = std::bit_cast<std::uintptr_t>(std::end(b));

assert(a_bits == b_bits);  // 2
```

The first assertion is allowed to pass (And does in unoptimized builds). When it does pass, the second usually does too. When `bit_cast` back to `int*`, what index should be valid? `[-1]` to get the value of `b[0]` (if it is `std::end(b)`), or `0` for `a[0]` (if it is `std::begin(a)`)? It seems to be unspecified

---

There are other cases where pointers can have the same value but be different. For an array `T[N]`, casting its address, a `T(*)[N]`, to `void*` will have the same value as casting a pointer to the first element, a `T*` to `void*`. The same happens when using an empty class member with `[[no_unique_address]]`.

Comment: _it seems like the intention was that padding bits are allowed to be changed_ Padding bits are part of object representation and your quote says _an object of type To whose object representation **is equal** to the object representation of From_. So padding bits originally couldn't change. And changing only padding bits doesn't change the value. But pointers is a good example of multiple values with the same value representation.